# "If a last argument lambda is passed to a function call outside the parentheses, passing no values for the default parameters is allowed"

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I'm reading the [Default Arguments](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) section of the Kotlin docs and I've come across this information block:

> But if a last argument lambda is passed to a function call outside the
>   parentheses, passing no values for the default parameters is allowed:

```
fun foo(bar: Int = 0, baz: Int = 1, qux: () -> Unit) { ... }

foo(1) { println("hello") } // Uses the default value baz = 1 
foo { println("hello") }    // Uses both default values bar = 0 and baz = 1
```

I'm trying to understand what is being said here.

I'm aware no values need to be passed for the first 2 parameters. The 3rd parameter seems to be a function returning `Unit` type.

That's all I got from their explanation: `But if a last argument lambda is passed to a function call outside the parentheses, passing no values for the default parameters is allowed`

I gather they're saying the 3rd parameter doesn't need to be passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the docs have now been [updated](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/pull/1302), hopefully the new wording is more clear.

Original answer below.

---

You need the context of the previous sentence and code block for this to make sense:

> If a default parameter precedes a parameter with no default value, the
>   default value can be used only by calling the function with named
>   arguments:
>
> ```
> fun foo(bar: Int = 0, baz: Int) { ... }
> ​
> foo(baz = 1) // The default value bar = 0 is used
> ```
>
> But if a last argument lambda is passed to a function call outside the
>   parentheses, passing no values for the default parameters is allowed:
>
> ```
> fun foo(bar: Int = 0, baz: Int = 1, qux: () -> Unit) { ... }
> ​
> foo(1) { println("hello") } // Uses the default value baz = 1 
> foo { println("hello") }    // Uses both default values bar = 0 and baz = 1
> ```

So in the general case, if you had default values for all but the last parameter, you'd have to explicitly name the last parameter when making a call to the function with only that parameter, since there would be no way for the compiler to know that you're trying to pass in that specific parameter and not simply the one that's first on the parameter list.

However, since the syntax of passing in a lambda outside the parentheses of a function call is restricted to lambdas that are the [very last parameter of the function](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter), the compiler can figure out that you're trying to pass in `qux` in the second example.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense - I understand how the syntax works now. But I'm just failing to see a viable example where it can be used.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where you want to pass a lambda to a function, and _sometimes_ parameterize how it uses it. For example, you might have an `execute` function you normally call with just the lambda `execute { println("foo") }`, but then it has default parameters where you can tweak how it executes your lambda, e..g `execute(thread = ..., times = 3) { println("foo") }`

Answer (score 0):

> But if a last argument lambda is passed to a function call outside the
>   parentheses, passing no values for the default parameters is allowed.

It means you can call `foo` function without parentheses like this:

```
foo { println("hello") } 
or
foo(1) { println("hello") }
or
foo(1, 2) { println("hello") }
```

With parentheses it would look like this (note that in the first two examples we need to specify parameter name `qux`):

```
foo(qux = { println("hello") })
or
foo(1, qux = { println("hello") })
or
foo(1, 2, { println("hello") })
```

Comment: Your fourth and fifth examples there won't work, you're passing in a lambda positionally for parameters that expect an `Int`.